# Is it possible to add to IConfiguration after the WebHost has started?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-systems-manager

I am using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store to hold database connection strings which are used to dynamically build a DbContext in my .NET Core Application

I am using the .NET Core AWS configuration provider (from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-configuration-provider-for-aws-systems-manager/) which injects my parameters into the IConfiguration at runtime.

At the moment I am having to keep my AWS access key/secret in code so it can be accessed by the ConfigurationBuilder but would like to move this out of the code base and stored it in appsettings or similar.

Here is my method to create the webhost builder called at startup

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx");

    AWSOptions options = new AWSOptions()
    {
        Credentials = credentials,
        Region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2
    };

    webHost.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        config.AddSystemsManager("/ParameterPath", options, reloadAfter: new System.TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)); // Reload every minute
    });

 return webHost;
}
```

I need to be able to inject the BasicAWSCredentials parameter from somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access an already built configuration to be able to retrieve the information you seek.

Consider building one to retrieve the needed credentials that would have been stored in the *appsettings* file

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {
    IWebHostBuilder builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

    //build configuration 
    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json") // or where ever the settings are stored
        .Build();

    //extract credentials
    string access_key = configuration.GetValue<string>("access_key:path_here");
    string secret_key = configuration.GetValue<string>("secret_key:path_here");

    //use credentials as desired
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key, secret_key);
    
    AWSOptions options = new AWSOptions() {
        Credentials = credentials,
        Region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2
    };

    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config => {
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        config.AddSystemsManager("/ParameterPath", options, reloadAfter: new System.TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)); // Reload every minute
    });

    return builder;
}
```

I would also suggest reviewing [Configuring AWS Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html) from the docs to use the SDK  to find a possible alternative way to storing and retrieving the credentials.

Comment: Ahh, of course - that makes perfect sense. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to do this.  There is a `webHost`, which has all the IConfiguration set up ready to go, why build another, separate one, with potentially different providers in it, to get something that /should/ already be in the config.

Comment: @Neil They will eventually be accessing the same configuration. The purpose of preemptively accessing and actually built configuration is to extract the relevant keys specific to aws in this scenario. Where would you have accessed that data since the web host configuration has not been configured or built as yet?

Comment: What if the keys are in appsettings.Development.json or secrets, or some other provider?  You are just (partially) duplicating what webhost has already done.  I've found another way, which, whilst is a little more verbose, does duplicate what the host is using (basically create a new ContainerBuilder, and add all the providers that the host has configured, into it).

Comment: @Neil I would suggest adding that as an answer so others can benefit from the knowledge, providing a better understanding of the topic